# How should event listeners be cleaned up in a React Component (while in Strict Mode)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a web app that needs a disappearing mobile menu. I have a `toggleMenu` function, which makes the menu appear and disappear. Right now everything works in production, and when not in strict mode, however when in strict mode the event listeners are added twice and don't work.

[image]

I know that strict mode calls componentDidMount twice and I don't want to disable it. I've tried updating my code so that the event listeners are removed when unmounting, but they don't seem to be removed.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMobileMenu: false,
      tabList: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Add event listeners to tabs
    let tempTabList = document.getElementsByClassName("react-tabs__tab");

    for (let i = 0; i < tempTabList.length; i++) {
      tempTabList[i].addEventListener("click", this.toggleMenu.bind(this));
    }
    
    this.setState({ tabList: tempTabList });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove event listeners from tabs
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.tabList.length; i++) {
      this.state.tabList[i].removeEventListener(
        "click",
        this.toggleMenu.bind(this)
      );
    }
  }

... more code here
```

I would expect that the componentDidMount function would set the event listeners, then the componentWillUnmount function would remove them, and then the componenetDidMount would once again add them, but it isn't working that way. What do I need to do to get this to work in strict mode?

Comment: I wouldn't use a state to store the `tabList` - just put it in an instance property. You may even use that to avoid adding the listeners twice, by checking whether it has already been initialised.

Comment: Where and how are the `.react-tabs__tab` elements rendered? Is there a particular reason why you attach the event handlers using dom methods?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer the question with the help of Bergi's comment. I just had to use a an instance variable to keep track of whether or not this was the first mount of the instance.

```
class ReportWithMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tabs = [];
    this.isInitialMount = true;
    this.state = {
      showMobileMenu: false,
    };
  }

  static tabList = document.getElementsByClassName("react-tabs__tab");

  componentDidMount() {  
    // Add event listeners to tabs
    this.tabList = document.getElementsByClassName("react-tabs__tab");
    if (this.isInitialMount) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.tabList.length; i++) {
        this.tabList[i].addEventListener("click", this.toggleMenu.bind(this));
      }
    }
    this.isInitialMount = false;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove event listeners from tabs
    for (let i = 0; i < this.tabList.length; i++) {
      this.tabList[i].removeEventListener(
        "click",
        this.toggleMenu.bind(this)
      );
    }
  }

... more code here
```